# Move bonobo git server repositories to another drive

Tags: git, iis, version-control, windows-server-2012-r2, bonobo

I use [Bonobo Git Server](https://bonobogitserver.com/), I want to move my repositories to another drive.

currently the repositories are in `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\App_Data\Repositories`. How can I move them to `D:\` drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell Bonobo where the repositories are, on the 'settings' page.  So just move your repositories directory to d:\ and go to the Bonobo settings and change them to match.  You don't need to try and fool Bonobo with a symlink.

You may need to fiddle with disk access permissions for whatever user your bonobo app pool runs under, same as you would with any IIS app which needs access to the file system.

Comment: Nice, is it posible to set to local notwork location (`e.g: 192.168.11.125\Repositories`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have administrative privileges on that machine, you can see if making a directory symlink.

Move your `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\App_Data\Repositories` folder first (so `App_Data\` has no longer the Repositories folder).

Then:

```
# In an Administrtor CMD shell:
mklink /D D:\path\top\Repositories C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Bonobo.Git.Server\App_Data\Repositories
```

That way, all the current Bonobo/IIS settings remain the same.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I use `Will Dean` solution

Answer (score 0):

go to the setting and give fully qualified path(E:\back-Up\r) in the Repository Directory and save the changes, hopefully it help you.